# In C program, I can I display using interrupt an alternate key if a key is pressed?

Tags: keyboard

For my project, how could I display alternate key for a key that was pressed. The requirement is to make use of interrupts to detect what key is pressed and output on the console, the alternate key for the key that was pressed. This is programming in C. I'm not familiar with handling keyboard interrupt.

Any help is very much appreciated!THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, keyboard interrupts are handled by device drivers. If you want to write a device driver, I believe there is a sample keyboard driver you can base your on in the [Windows DDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487463) (now called the WDK).

If you just want to substitute keys, you can do so with a registry hack. See [Scan Code Mapper for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx) for instructions.